# run javascript on page load to hide form

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript to hide a form if the user clicks on a checkbox.

I am trying to get the code to run on page load but am not able to work out how to do this. Can anyone help?

```
$('#no_cage').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#cage_details').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('#cage_details').fadeIn();
  }                   
});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="no_cage" id="no_cage" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo $checked; ?>><label for="no_cage">Check if not required</label>

<div id="cage_details">

<form>

...

</form>

</div>
```

This works fine when a user clicks on the checkbox. But does not when it pulls from the DB and the checkbox is already selected on page load.

Comment: do you want to trigger the event on page load or to register your handler?

Comment: please provide html content too for wider idea of your issue.

Comment: Please provide a full example, with markup, as well as the script for this action. It is important to determine your script load as well as additional code you have.

Comment: I have now included the HTML. I am not good with JS so appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this code inside the document ready handler.  It will trigger the change event handler without it needing to actually change...

```
$('#no_cage').trigger("change");
```

Alternatively, just trigger the event where you declare it...

```
$('#no_cage').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#cage_details').fadeOut();
    }
    else {
        $('#cage_details').fadeIn();
    }                   
}).trigger("change");
```

That will add the event handler and then immediately execute it, in order to set the form to the correct state when the document has loaded.

Comment: How do I get the form to reset when someone clicks on the checkbox?

Comment: Try adding `$("#cage_details").find("form")[0].reset();`

Answer (score -2):

You can either change the checked property or trigger the change event.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#no_cage').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#cage_details').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('#cage_details').fadeIn();
    }
  });

  // Change the checked property
  $('#no_cage').prop('checked', true);

  // OR trigger the change event
  // $('#no_cage').trigger('change');

});
```